# Trie data structure

Tags: data-structures, stack

Given N strings. Each string contains only lowercase letters from `a−j` (both inclusive). The set of N strings is said to be **GOOD SET** if no string is prefix of another string else, it is **BAD SET**.

For example, `aab`, `abcde`, `aabcd` is **BAD SET** because `aab` is prefix of `aabcd`.

Print **GOOD SET** if it satisfies the problem requirement. 
Else, print **BAD SET** and the first string for which the condition fails.

**Input Format:**
First line contains N, the number of strings in the set. 
Then next N lines follow, where ith line contains ith string.

**Constraints:**
1 ≤ N ≤ 105 
1 ≤ Length of the string ≤60

**Output Format:**
Output **GOOD SET** if the set is valid.
Else, output **BAD SET** followed by the first string for which the condition fails.

Can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), inserting each string to the trie one by one, recording the pointers to nodes representing each string inserted in trie. Once done, scan the node pointers for all strings. If any of those ends at internal node, then it is a BAD SET. otherwise, (all string ends on distinct leaves), it is a GOOD SET. Time and space complexity are both linear to the total length of all strings.